# Drawing regular grid over map formed by set of points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

By using QGIS, is it possible to draw a regular grid over a surface formed by a set of points, by using an assigned grid dimension (expressed as fraction of degrees of latitude or longitude)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here should demonstrate an effort to solve the problem. Please [Edit] your question to specify the exact QGIS release in use, what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I think your question would benefit by the inclusion of a picture to illustrate what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

In **QGIS 2.18**:

Use **Vector > Research Tools > Vector Grid**.

You can select the layer extent manually, from the canvas, or by using the extent of the layer in question, which can be found in that layer's Metadata: **Right click on layer in Table of Contents > Properties > Metadata > Properties > Extents**